# How to prevent Vim to collapse a fold with foldmethod=indent on a text paste?

Tags: indentation, folding

I have the `foldmethod=indent` setting, the problem with it is that when I'm pasting a line or lines before the first line of a fold and all of these lines have the same or a greater level of indentation as the fold in question, the fold collapses.

Here is a screen shot:

[image: a fold collapses on paste]

And here is a gif animation of my actions in Vim with default settings:

[image: a fold collapses on paste example]

How can I prevent this behavior? I would like the fold to remain open regardless of where I paste and what I paste.

If I paste not on the first line of a fold, or the text pasted has at least one line which has a lesser indentation level, an empty line for instance, the fold doesn't collapse.

I tried to set `foldmethod=manual` before a paste, similar to a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922267/vim-opens-my-folds-on-paste-how-to-prevent-that#4701478), but it seems there is no such event for the autocommand, for instance something like `TextChangedPrev`.

---

Currently, I suppose, that this is a bug, which has to do something with a way how Vim handles indentation folds. The folds are defined only by the number of white spaces from the "0 column".

- If I paste a line with the indentation smaller, than the fold's one, the pasted line is considered to belong to a previous fold.
- If I paste a line with indentation level bigger than the fold's one, then it creates a new fold, technically and should be indented (or shouldn't, since blocks smaller than two lines are not indented, as far as I know.
- But if I paste a line with the same indentation as the fold's one at the fold's first line, I would suppose that line to be treated like a line in the currently, already existing fold.

**And this is a bug supposedly, since it looks like Vim for some reason miscounts the indentation and thinks that a new fold has just been created**, so it takes all lines above and below, which have the same indent level and collapses them.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Have you checked that it doesn't come from a setting in your vimrc? See [How do I debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841)

Comment: @statox, I've added a gif file in order to show what happens in a more clearer way

Comment: Indeed with your gif I can reproduce your problem but I can't explain it, sorry :)